# hibernate / suspend problems

Tags: debian, xfce, thinkpad, i3, pm-utils

#### Problem

The <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> function key combination does not result in hibernating, instead it resets the internet connection instead

#### Symptoms

`pm-hibernate` and `pm-suspend` just reset the connection. `hibernate` works, as does `s2both`.

#### Setup

Lenovo X230, updated Debian testing, 3.14 kernel, i3 wm, lightdm, xfce4-power-manager.

On Lenovos, <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd> is a special function key, which is supposed to hibernate the machine (moon symbol).

Since `pm-hibernate` is not working, the idea was to change the handler to `s2both`. I cannot find the script responsible for handling the key press though. Other system keys work as expected (volume, mute, etc).

Things I've tried:

1. Catching `XF86Sleep` or `XF86WakeUp` in `.i3/config` (my window manager config file). This file is handling some of the other special buttons like `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`. Variations on`bindsym XF86Sleep exec "hibernate"`. No effect.
2. Switching out the backend for pm by adding `SLEEP_MODULE=uswsusp` in `/etc/pm/config.d/module`. No effect.
3. Modyfying `etc/acpi/sleep_suspend.sh` to use `hibernate` or `s2both`. No effect.
4. Poking around `xfce4-power-manager` setting GUI. Nothing here.

#### Questions

- Can someone please explain who is handling the power options here? ACPI? xfce4-power-manager?
- What is the relationship between these?
- What happens when I press <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>?
- Who is handling the key press and how do I change / fix it?
- What is the best practice for handling suspends / hibernates gracefully?

Comment: Take a look at thinkwiki: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_get_special_keys_to_work. See if any of this proves helpful in getting this working.

Comment: The key works. The key press is not being handled properly.

Answer (score 1):

On my thinkpad I use `xbindkey` to do this.

Setup:

1. Install xbindkeys `apt-get install xbindkeys`
2. Edit your config `~/.xbindkeysrc.scm`

   `(xbindkey '("XF86Standby") "sudo pm-suspend")`
3. Run xbindkeys in i3/config

   `exec --no-startup-id xbindkeys&`

or in the `.xinitrc`

`xbindkeys &`